# Java Inner class compilation error

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

I'm trying to instantiate a public non-static inner class but I keep getting a compilation error.

I have 2 classes: a tree class and a main class.

I'm ultimately trying to instantiate an array of points, but for the sake of this question, I'm trying to just instantiate a Point object.

The compilation error says that

> Point can't be resolved to a type

What am I doing wrong?

Tree.java

```
public class Tree<T> {  
    public class Point<T> {
        public T position[];
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Point<Double> point = new Tree<Point<Double>>().new Point<Double>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `Point` doesn't exist - `Tree.Point` does. But do you *really* want two different type parameters? I suspect either `Tree` or `Point` shouldn't be generic.

Comment: For example, if `Point` isn't generic, you'd have `Tree<Double>.Point point = new Tree<Double>().new Point();`

Comment: An inner class can be public. And this is for a project and he gave us the code and it uses generics.

Comment: Well you must be doing it wrong because mine compiles fine.

Comment: I'm writing this in eclipse. It works.

Comment: Tree and main are two different files.

Comment: The error is clear. It doesn't have to do anything with inner class but proper resolution. Main class addressing the inner class of Tree.

Comment: Oh and thanks to whoever downvoted my post for no reason.

Comment: You are not using anywhere `T` declared in `Tree<T>` since `Point` is declared its own `<T>` which shadows one from `Tree`. In other words your code is like `class Tree<A> {  class Tree<B> {   public B position[]; } }` (no `A` is used here so it is redundant, why do you even have it?).

Comment: Ok I think I understand what your saying. I don't know why the hell he wrote it like that. I'll probably just end up changing it. Thanks!

Comment: You can also remove `<B>` declaration and change your array type to `A[]`. IMO it makes more sense to have generic type for entire tree and make each Point use it, but it all depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: I think what I have to do is make a Tree of type Point and then each of those points have to be of type Double. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: You are probably overcomplicating it. Tree already knows it has Point type inside. What we need to specify is if each Point can store elements of its own type *in same Tree* like `class Tree{ class Point<T> { []T ...}}`, or if all Points in same Tree should hold same type of elements `class Tree<T>{class Point{ T[] ...}}`. I suspect second case is more probable. If that is true you can try writing something like `Tree<Double> tree = new Tree<>(); Tree<Double>.Point point = tree.new Point();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you don't want to have two different type parameters for `Tree` and `Point`. The way you wrote it, the `T` of `Point` shades the `T` of `Tree`, so the parameters are actually different. If you want them to be the same, remove the `T` of the inner class. This way the `T` of outer class can be used in the inner class as well.

```
public class Tree<T> {  
    public class Point {
        public T position[];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tree<Double>.Point point = new Tree<Double>().new Point();
    }
}
```

If you *really* want to have two different `T`s, you can instantiate a `Point` like this. But then I highly recommend to rename one of the type parameters to prevent confusion.

```
Tree<Object>.Point<Double> point = new Tree<>().new Point<>();
```

**Edit**: According to the comments:

```
Tree<Tree<?>.Point<Double>>.Point<Double> point = new Tree<Tree<?>.Point<Double>>().new Point<>();
```

**Edit**: According to further comments

Since you want a `Tree` to contain always Points, there is no use in using generics here. It is a little bit dependent on what you want to do with this class, whether to remove the type parameter of `Tree` of the one of `Point`.

**Possibility 1** removing type parameter of `Tree`

```
public class Tree {  
    public class Point<T> {
        public T position[];
    }
}
```

You can go with that if you want to return a `Point` from the methods in the `Tree`

**Possibility 2** removing type parameter of `Point`

```
public class Tree<T> {  
    public class Point {
        public T position[];
    }
}
```

You should go with that if you want the methods in `Tree` to return objects of type `T`

Comment: I want the type of point to be Double and I want the type of tree to be Point.

Comment: @namarino you are right, I'm sorry. I edited my answer, now it compiles. But you should really consider removing that `T` at `Point` class. Do you have any reason why the inner class has to have a type parameter?

Comment: Well this is for a class and the code that they gave us is written like that.So it wasn't my design decision.

Comment: Ok, i don't understand why anyone should build classes like this. But if you really want to have it, you can instantiate a Point like this `Tree<Tree<?>.Point<Double>>.Point<Double> point = new Tree<Tree<?>.Point<Double>>().new Point<>();`

Comment: Oh I think I understand. So basically what you're saying is that because the two classes have the same type T, there's no use in having the <T> with Point because as you're instantiating Tree<T>, you're instantiating Point<T> with the same type. So it's redundant. Is that correct??

Comment: So if I want to make a Point of type Double and Tree of type Point, how would I go about doing that??

Comment: I think you don't actually want a `Tree` of type `Point`. I think you propably want a `Tree` consisting of `Point`s of type `Double`. Or do you want to be able to do a `Tree` of something different than a `Point`? E. g. a `Tree<Double>`

Comment: Oh you might be right actually. Since the tree isn't really going to vary in terms of what it contains (its always going to contain points and nodes) I don't really need generics. So do I just remove the Generic tag from Tree?

Comment: @namarino I updated my answer again. I hope this will help you out!

Comment: @namarino: Please don't go begging for votes like that, or complain that people have downvoted "for no reason". If you want to get upvotes, write better questions. I didn't downvote, it's not a really *bad* question, but it's not a *great* one either. You might find it useful to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I'm not begging, I'm politely asking. And since it's the difference between never being able to ask a question again and getting a bad grade on my project in my class and asking someone to upvote a good question, I think I'll ask. Thanks.

Comment: I've asked numerous question on this site that have been blocked despite the fact that other people have asked practically the same question and had no problems. This is not a bad question. It's a fine question. We had good discussion and I learned what I needed to learn.

Comment: And also, why should a "not _great_ question" get me kicked off the site? That's complete and utter nonsense. If it's not an egregiously bad question it shouldn't get downvoted and I shouldn't get banned.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually I think this is a question a lot of people could have. I'd just propose the question could be edited to be a little bit more general. I would also say, the question is not *great* but it's surely not so bad that it should be downvoted

Comment: @SilverNak: Right, but without that editing I don't think it's worth upvoting, and requesting upvotes is a bad idea IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave out the T parameter when declaring the inner class.

Just use T inside, but don't try to redefine a type parameter with the same name T.

Comment: I can't leave out the generic.

Comment: If you want to use the same T that the outer class has, then you do **not** need it. If the inner class needs a different type parameter then rename T to S for example!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments:

```
Tree<Double>.Point<Double> point = new Tree<Double>().new Point<Double>();
```

but it looks like a little bit too redundant don't you think?

you can remove the generic part of point

```
public class Tree<T> {
    public class Point {
        public T position[];
    }
}


Tree<Double>.Point point = new Tree<Double>().new Point();
```